# Map returned by ApplicationContext.getBeansOfType changing - WebFluxTest SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-webflux

I'm trying to make a controller test. And I found some difficulties when testing applicationContext.getBeansOfType in the controller.

So here are the snippets of my controller code looks like

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/bridge")
public class BridgeController {

    @RequestMapping(
      value = "/visitor",
      method = RequestMethod.POST
    )
    public Mono<Response<Boolean>> visitorEvent(
      @RequestBody VisitorEventWebRequest webRequest) {

      return Mono
          .fromCallable(() -> constructVisitorEventCommandRequest(webRequest))
          .flatMap(register -> 
              commandExecutor.execute(getVisitorFactory(webRequest).getClass(),register)
              .subscribeOn(SchedulerHelper);
     }
}
```

with getVisitorFactory(webRequest) is a method to call the beans instance of service based on its eventType(this is a field in webRequest)

```
private VisitorEventAbstract getVisitorFactory(VisitorEventWebRequest webRequest) {
    try {
      VisitorEventAbstract command = this.applicationContext.getBeansOfType(VisitorEventAbstract.class)
          .getOrDefault(webRequest.getEventType(), null);

      if(command == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
      }

      return command;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Error getting visitor event abstract implementation for event type : {}",
          webRequest.getEventType());
      throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

And then, in my controller test, I have mock the applicationContext.getBeansOfType and it will return a map that I had declared in the @Before method. I'm using SpringExtension and WebFluxTest. The snippet is below

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebFluxTest(controllers = BridgeController.class)
public class BridgeVisitorControllerTest {

   @Autowired
   private WebTestClient testClient;

   @MockBean
   private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

   @MockBean
   private RegisterEventCommandImpl registerEventCommandImpl;

   private Map<String, VisitorEventAbstract> visitorEventAbstractContext;

   @BeforeEach
   public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    this.visitorEventAbstractContext = new HashMap<>();
    this.visitorEventAbstractContext.put("REGISTRATION", this.registerEventCommandImpl);
  }

  @Test
  public void execute() {

   /// some code

   when(applicationContext.getBeansOfType(VisitorEventAbstract.class))
        .thenReturn(this.visitorEventAbstractContext);
   when(commandExecutor.execute(eq(VisitorEventAbstract.class), any()))
        .thenAnswer(ans -> Mono.just(Boolean.TRUE));

   /// testClient.post()

  }
}
```

So, since I have initialized the map, and mock the applicationContext, I expect when the controllerTest run, in the getVisitorFactory(webRequest method),it will return the map like this

> {
>   "key" : "REGISTRATION",
>   "value" : RegisterEventCommandImpl (bean instance that have been mocked)
>   }

but, in actual, the map returned always changed the key like this :

> {
>   "key" : "{package name of the RegisterEventCommandImpl}",
>   "value" : RegisterEventCommandImpl (bean instance)
>   }

which make my test always failed because they can't find the bean with key "REGISTRATION". please help, what am I missing? and why the key is always change like that?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: why register beans in the spring context in the first place, if you are only going to retrieve them manually?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf do you mean in the test class? because if I'm not initialize it, when that particular function (applicationContext.getBeansOfType) is called, it will not return any map. please correct my understanding if it's wrong.